# PhantomJS "not available in path" when called through Fitnesse (CSlim) with Python API

Tags: python, c, selenium, phantomjs, fitnesse

I'm trying to create some automated tests using a combination of Selenium and Fitnesse on a Linux machine. I am using the Python bindings of Selenium and CSlim as a wrapper for Fitnesse.

Previously I have been calling python files from CSlim using the *system()* command e.g.

```
system( "python CurrentCommand.py" );
```

However, to pass any outputs from the Python scripts back to Fitnesse requires the creation of logfiles. In an effort to improve things I have used the C Python API (2.63) within CSlim so that I can call Python code without using *system()* or creating logfiles.

Whilst I have this working perfectly in a simple C file, when the exact same code is pasted into a fixture and called from Fitnesse I am getting the following error:

```
  File "/home/dm1506/test_centre/fitnesse/selenium/run_selenium/SeleniumTestLib.py", line 93, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=TLSv1'])

  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium-2.53.6-py2.6.egg/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.service.start()

  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium-2.53.6-py2.6.egg/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
    (os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message, str(e)))

  selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The executable phantomjs needs to be available in the path. 

  [Errno 10] No child processes
```

I can call the python code without a problem but for some reason it can no longer see the PhantomJS executable. It is definitely in the path though, I have printed the path from the Fitnesse-called Python instance and can see that PhantomJS is contained within it. I have also tried giving the explicit path when calling PhantomJS i.e.

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/path/to/phantomjs-1.9.2-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs')
```

But this does not work either. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or know what might be causing this?